# Using a plist in an iOS app to retain data for a multi-step form

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios5, plist

I have a multi-step form in an iOS application. To retain my data for the last step, I am using a plist. Is it the preferred way, or are there any better techniques to keep retained values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably not use a plist. Store your form values in NSDictionary and pass the dictionary to the next view controller.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that plist would be overkill. Just use the convenient preferences mechanism and save in case of interruptions.

Keep an `NSMutableDictionary` around in all view controllers to hold the data. Add data as soon as you can, i.e. for instance when the user switches away from a text field, etc.

Then, in `applicationWillEnterBackground` of your AppDelegate, do something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:myMutualDictionary]
            forKey:@"UserInput"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you use plist to retain data use an array or dictionary.

Comment: b/c i intend to retain user data from throughout the app, and when user leaves the form in the middle the data should be held in someway